# jQuery: How should I structure a new list that's generated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

*edit: This question is about jQuery refactoring. Basically I have a big block of code but I want to see if other folks can think of a better way to refactor it. Since I'm new to jQuery I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not with my design*

*original post:*
I'm working on a bookmarklet which adds HTML elements to the page. I'm building a sidebar which is a div with a ul inside of it. I'm trying to keep my styles separate from my code and to also write things so that they will be easy to manage if I need to make changes in the future. Is it possible to refactor this code to make it cleaner/more efficient?

```
myObj = {
$sidebar: {},   
createSidebar: function () {
    var self = this, $undo = {}, $redo = {}, $email = {}, $reset = {}

    self.$sidebar = $("<div id='myObj-sidebar'><ul></ul></div>");

    $undo = $('<a></a>', {
        id: 'sidebar-undo',
        className: 'sidebar-item',
        href: '#',
        text: 'Undo',
        click: function (e) {
            //self.doUndo();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $redo = $('<a></a>', {
        id: 'sidebar-redo',
        className: 'sidebar-item',
        href: '#',
        text: 'Redo',
        click: function (e) {
            //self.doRedo();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $email = $('<a></a>', {
        id: 'sidebar-change-email',
        className: 'sidebar-item',
        href: '#',
        text: 'Change E-Mail',
        click: function (e) {
            //self.createEmailDialog();
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
    });

    $reset = $('<a></a>', {
        id: 'sidebar-reset-all',
        className: 'sidebar-item',
        href: '#',
        text: 'Reset All',
        click: function (e) {
            //self.doReset();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    self.$sidebar.find('ul').append($undo, $redo, $email, $reset);
    self.$sidebar.find('.sidebar-item').wrap('<li/>');
    self.$sidebar.appendTo("body");
}
}
```

Comment: This question is very vague. Could you be more specific?

Comment: altered the question so that it's more specific. basically just looking for refactoring tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the question is - my interpretation is that you're asking for refactoring advice.  If that's what you're looking for, here's the way I'd probably implement the same requirements:

```
jQuery('<div><ul></ul></div>')
  .appendTo("body")
  .css({
    background: "white",
    left: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    textAlign: "left",
    top: '50%'
  })
  .find('ul')
    .css({
      listStyleType: 'none',
      margin: 0,
      padding: 0
    })
    .append('<li><a href="" class="sidebar-undo">Undo</a></li>')
    .find('.sidebar-undo')
      .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your 'undo' code
      })
      .end()
    .append('<li><a href="" class="sidebar-redo">Redo</a></li>')
    .find('.sidebar-redo')
      .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your 'redo' code
      })
      .end()
    .append('<li><a href="" class="sidebar-changeEmail">Change E-Mail</a></li>')
    .find('.sidebar-changeEmail')
      .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your 'changeEmail' code
      })
      .end()
    .append('<li><a href="" class="sidebar-doReset">Reset All</a></li>')
    .find('.sidebar-doReset')
      .click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        // your doReset code
      })
      .end()
    .find('li')
      .css({
        padding: '0.5em'
      })
      .end()
    .find('a')
      .css({
        background: "whatever",
        color: "etc"
      });
```

Notes:

- `e.preventDefault()` should generally be the first line of your handler, that way if an exception is thrown later, the anchor will still not navigate (easier to debug);
- you don't need to give any of your elements IDs, since you have direct DOM handles on everything already;
- your hrefs should ideally be useful, taking the user to a legitimate page if they right-click and do "open in new tab" (using "preventDefault" will keep them from navigating away on regular left-click);
- since it's a bookmarklet, don't worry too much about separating out your styles - you're using jQuery, so you can easily grab the elements you care about and apply CSS properties directly;
- the example above has no variables aside from the `e` event object - to me, this is a more elegant solution than creating a `self` reference  and a bunch of collection objects (that's just my opinion).

Hope this helps!

Comment: very helpful, going through it all now. Thanks!

*edit:*
• thanks for the point about e.preventDefault, that's a really great tip.

• per your 2nd and 4th points, the code above is only a small piece of the bookmarklet (it's actually quite large at this point) so I wanted to separate the styles so my designer could work on CSS and not have to touch my code, that's why there's no styling in the jquery.

• the hrefs just run other js functions that manipulate the page DOM so they don't actually go anywhere, that's why I used '#'. hopefully that's ok?

sorry this comment looks insane

Comment: generally I recommend against using '#' as the URL, even if you don't need the link to go anywhere.  The reason is because you really don't want it to go to '#'.  If there's no reasonable href, then it may be appropriate to not use anchors at all - that is, if there's no place the link would ever "go", then maybe another element (such as a span, or just the li) would make more sense.

Comment: ok. I was just guessing that it was more semantic to use an anchor since it's a clickable element but I see your point as well. It's all gray area in terms of my understanding :D I'm still a pretty big newb to html/js